# Exception for bibliography style

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I am using Jabref to generate my bibliography (overall style apacite) and would like to have these two entries in the bibliography as

```
British Library, Title of Manuscript notes XYZ, Asia and Africa Collections, Private Paper, reference MSS EUR F88/341

Youtube.com, www.linkofthevideo.com, accessed on Sept 10, 2012
```

How/where can I fill in the relevant entries in Jabref to get such type of entry? Or alternatively how can I enter the details in the bib file, please? Or make exceptions to the existing style?

Comment: Use `author = "{British Library}"` in your `bib` file

Comment: For the second one I would use `@misc` with `title = "Youtube.com`, `url = "www.linkofthevideo.com"` and `lastchecked = "Sept 10, 2012"`. Though `apacite` might not format the entry exactly as you want.

Comment: @Guido Since your comments seem to answer the question, why not convert them into an answer?

Answer (score 3):

For the first issue you can enclose the author name in braces, i.e.,

```
author = "{British Library}"
```

For the second one, a possibility would be to use `@misc` for the entry.

```
@misc{key,
   title = "Youtube.com", 
   url = "www.linkofthevideo.com", 
   lastchecked = "Sept 10, 2012"
}
```

Though apacite might not format the entry exactly as you want.